# which densities are Lipschitz in this sense?

Tags: density-function

Suppose $f(\cdot)$ is the pdf of some random variable with support $S\subset R$ ($S$ could equal to $R$). Suppose $x,y$ are two points in $S$, and $\beta_1,\beta_2$ are two scalars that belong to a compact parameter space $\mathscr{B}\subset R$.

Which densities are Lipschitz in the following sense:

$|f(y+x\beta_1)-f(y+x\beta_2)|\leq B(x,y)|\beta_1-\beta_2|$ for any $\beta_1,\beta_2\in\mathscr{B}$ and any $x,y\in S$?

Comment: What kind of answer are you hoping for?  A list won't do -- there are too many possibilities.  And what are the implicit quantifiers in your question?  After all, since you appear to have fixed two points $x$ and $y,$ you scarcely need to indicate them in the coefficient $B(x,y),$ suggesting you are trying to ask something more general.

Comment: @whuber Thanks, Whuber! I worked out that this condition is implicitly required in a paper, and I just want to have some idea of how strong this condition is. For example, does normal density, logistic density and other commonly seen densities satisfy this condition?

Comment: @whuber I guess as long as $f(\cdot)$ is continuous, then this condition is satisfied.

Comment: @JTS365 how does that follow?

Comment: @rubikscube09 You are right, this condition implies continuity, not the other way around.

Comment: As for your question, I think most common densities should satisfy this definition as they are smooth with bounded derivatives of all orders.

Comment: @rubikscube09 Thanks! Is it necessary to have bounded derivatives of all orders? Seems that having a bounded 1st order derivative would suffice, right?

Comment: It's enough that the first derivative is continuous. For fixed $x$, $y$, we have that $(y+x\beta_1, y+x\beta_2)$ ranges over a compact set, so if the first derivative is continuous is it also bounded. The bound varies with $x$ and $y$, so $B(x,y)$ handles that.

Comment: @ThomasLumley Thanks! I think this looks correct.

Comment: @rubiks Except, of course, for the really common densities that don't have this property, such as Exponential, Uniform, Pareto, and Beta with one or both parameters less than or equal to $1$ :-).

Comment: @whuber well i think I specified the conditions I felt were necessary so I don't believe my answer was entirely misleading